WordPress Themes Problem , Blank white page themes

I have a problem with wordpress themes where at first when i first installed it some themes like astra worked and all the banners are displayed but some of them are like blank pages like the image below , but when i add a page with a title and pubish it all the themes turn into white pages like that even the ones whoi worked before , please is there a solution for this.
I tried deleting teh databse and trying again but the same problem

Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
